# Unkown command `J` while ssh to Ubuntu machine from windows through jump host

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I am trying to connect to a remote VM installed with Ubuntu on AWS, from a windows machine using putty over jump bastion host. and I am getting unknow command J.

Steps:

1. I am navigating to the putty installed folder.
2. Then send this command `putty.exe -ssh user_name@<target_server> -J  jump_user@<jump_bastion_host>`

Is there anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes check the manual. Check order of arguments.

`ssh «options» «destination» «command»`

Therefore `-J  jump_user@<jump_bastion_host>` is being interpreted as a command.

Comment: Oh got it, I guess I need to change the order of command to `ssh.exe  -J  jump_user@<jump_bastion_host>  user_name@<target_server>`

Comment: @JYOTIPRAKASHMALLICK If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).